# get parents element of a tag using python requests-HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-crawler, python-requests-html

hi is There any way to get all The parent elements of a Tag using requests-HTML?

for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body id="two">
    <h1 class="text-primary">hello there</h1>
    <p>one two tree<b>four</b>five</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get all parent of `b` tag: `[html, body, p]`

or for the `h1` tag get this result: `[html, body]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the excellent `lxml` :

```py
from lxml import etree
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body id="two">
    <h1 class="text-primary">hello there</h1>
    <p>one two tree<b>four</b>five</p>
</body>
</html> """
tree = etree.HTML(html)
# We search the first <b> element
b_elt = tree.xpath('//b')[0]
print(b_elt.text)
# -> "four"
# Walking around ancestors of this <b> element
ancestors_tags = [elt.tag for elt in b_elt.iterancestors()]
print(ancestors_tags)
# -> [p, body, html]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the lower level *lxml* [`Element`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) via the `element` attribute which has an [`iterancestors()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iterancestors)

Here is how you could do it:

```py
from requests_html import HTML

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <body id="two">
       <h1 class="text-primary">hello there</h1>
       <p>one two tree<b>four</b>five</p>
    </body>
</html>"""
html = HTML(html=html)
b = html.find('b', first=True)
parents = [a for a in b.element.iterancestors()]
```

Comment: What is 'a' in parents = [a for a in b.element.iterancestors()] ?

Comment: D.O. this is list comprehension equivalent to
list = []
for a in b.element.iterancestors():
  list.append(a)